# When did walking from Ner Israel yeshiva to Baltimore no longer require Eruv Techumin?

Tags: halacha, history, chutz-laaretz, eruv-techumin

From what I'm told, several decades ago one who wanted to walk from Ner Israel yeshiva on Mt. Wilson Lane in Pikesville, MD to the greater Baltimore community (e.g. Rabbi Heinemann's shul, the Agudah, 6202 Park Heights Ave) on Shabbos would require an *eruv Techumin*, as the two environs were deemed non-contiguous. I've also heard that this is no longer required.

At what point did this change, and exactly why? (E.g. what was built that changed it? What year was that? And who gave the psak?)

Comment: This is still a subject of dispute.  R' Berger holds you don't need one.  R' Tzvi Berkowitz says you should still place one (although in principle I think he agrees).  Some people still place one.

Comment: Probably when houses were built between the two.

Comment: @YEZ thank you. Those who do place one -- where do they place it? Near the I-695?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @Shalom Usually people place it by either the 7-11 or what used to be Wells Fargo/Wachovia.  Which is right by 695.

Comment: My rabbi placed one in the Hilton near 695.

Comment: There are close votes on this question, though they haven't been explained. It appears that the anonymous close-voter thought that this question is "about Jews, rather than about Judaism." I disagree, because it asks about a halachic decision, and what factors changed that caused this shift in accepted halacha, which is completely on-topic, IMO.

Answer (score 7):

This is actually still a matter of dispute.

Rabbi Yosef Berger, posek of the Yeshiva and Rov of Kehillas Kol Torah in Baltimore, holds that you do not need to make an eruv techumin.  R' Tzvi Berkowitz holds that one should still place one, although he agrees it is a stringency.

Rabbi Eli Steinhardt, a Rebbe in the Yeshiva, walks from the Yeshiva into Baltimore every Rosh Hashana to daven from the amud at one of the shuls.  He places an eruv techumin for his walk.

[image: Map of the Pikesville area, northwest of Baltimore. There is a black circle around the interchange between I-695 Baltimore Beltway and MD-140 Reistersteown Rd., and a red dot off of the northern side of Resiterstown Rd., about a block northwest of the interchange.]

The top left is Ner Israel.  Middle right is the approximate outskirts of the Pikesville community.  The black circle in the middle is the potential problem area.  The small red dot to the top left of the circle is where I know people to have placed the eruv.  Pardon my graphical artistry skills.

Comment: +1 if you could include a map with relevant lines and locations on it that would improve this answer. Also if you could identify what the dispute is about that would also be nice (I assume they both know the Metziut).

Comment: @DoubleAA I asked my rabbi and he said that the main dispute is because the city boundary must be squared off before measuring the techum. In this case, the precise method of squaring off the boundary is in dispute. With one method, Ner Yisrael would be inside the limits, with another, it would not. Example could be square of using the cardinal directions (north, south east and west) while another method would be along the actual borders (somewhat tilted). Note that this is an example as to what it could be, not what the actual dispute is. Check with the rabbonim there.

Comment: @sabbahillel Ah! Now that's what I was interested in hearing. If anyone (YEZ) can find more details on this machloket (eg. names of Achronim and citations in Shulchan Arukh) that would be most interesting.